# linear regression in statsmodel.formula.api python

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, least-squares

I am using `statsmodels.formula.api` to preform linear regression. I have used three independent variables for prediction. In some cases I am getting negative value but all the output should be positive.

Is there any way to tell the model that the output can not be negative?

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

output1 = smf.ols(formula= 'y ~A+B+C', data= data).fit()
output = output.predict(my_data)
```